# Groovy script to merge thousands of flowfiles into one flowfile

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I am getting thousands of flowfiles from RouteToAttribute processor and before writing them to HDFS I want to merge them into a single File.

[Merge Record configuration I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VgSC.png)

I want to get data these files which is Json file format and merge them into one json file and send it to WriteToHDFS processor. MergeRecord is not able to serve the purpose so I am trying to do it with groovy but I am new to groovy so not able to crack it. Can someone please suggest.

Comment: Could you update the post, With the issues that you have faced with `MergeRecord` processor?

Comment: Additionally can you share what you have tried with groovy and what is not working?

Comment: You can also do this with regular MergeContent, if you need an array of json then set the header to '[', delimiter to ',', and footer to ']', if you don't need an array then it will just put one json doc after another by default, but MergeRecord should also work fine

Comment: I have linked the configuration of MergeRecord processor in my question